# Cannot find error in array management code

Tags: javascript

I can't find the error in this code. The function is intended to select and store data to an array.

```
  var array= new Array(50);
  array[0]= "Body";
  array[1]= "head";
  document.writeln(array[0] + " " + array[1]);

  function getData(name){
    var data = new Array(19);
    if (  name == "Load" ) {
      data[0] = "1";
      data[1] =" 2";
      data[2]="3";
    } else if ( name == "Add" ) { 
      data[0] = "0";
      data[1] =" 0";
      data[2]="3";
    } else ( 
      document.writeln("Error");
    }

 getData("Add");
```

Comment: `else (` should be `else {` for a start which means that you're missing the final close curly bracket on your function. If you formatted your code a little better you might have spotted that.

Comment: `else { (document.writeln("Error"); }` parenthesis instead of curly bracket. Also missing curly bracket to enclose function.

Comment: You may have a reason to initialize the size of your arrays, in which case ignore this comment. However, you may not be a "JavaScript developer" and are just translating your skills from another language-- in which case, be aware that JavaScript arrays are dynamic and will grow as you push into them or otherwise add new members.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code with a couple of amendments. You're not actually returning anything from the function, and since `data` is an array only local to that function, that's probably what you want to do since you won't be able to access it otherwise.

```
var array = new Array(50); array[0] = "Body"; array[1] = "head";
console.log(array[0] + " " + array[1]); // Body head

function getData(name) {
    var data = new Array(19);

    if (name == "Load") {
        data[0] = "1";
        data[1] = " 2";
        data[2] = "3";
    } else if (name == "Add") {
        data[0] = "0";
        data[1] = " 0";
        data[2] = "3";
    } else { // change the parenthesis to curly bracket
        console.log("Error");
    }
    return data; // return the array
} // close function curly bracket

var data = getData("Add"); // your array
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/desrjtbo/)

Comment: I have the feeling that He doesn't know exactly what he wants